# Build includes sprite packer atlas and its original textures

Tags: unity, android, textures, texture-atlas, build-process

I use Unity's Sprite Packer, it's working great. However, when I looked at the build report (in the Editor.log) it turns out that the build often includes the generated atlas texture and its original textures too. It wastes too much space. I checked the size of the unzipped APK and the build report was correct. I tried several configurations (adding and removing textures) but I could not find any regularities.

Some observations: - I could reproduce this only if I use 25+ textures in an atlas with variable sizes. - Texture compression settings did not matter. Packer policy could modify the result but did not solve the problem.

Has anybody had similar experience? I can upload my test project if necessary.

Comment: Are you on the latest version of Unity?

Comment: Yes i just updated yesterday (5.4.2f2).

Comment: You may want to submit a bug to the Unity team.  https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/bug-reporting

Comment: I already submited just trying to find solutions. Thanks!

Comment: Can you share your project structure? maybe your original assets are in a Resources folder which is automatically added to the build.